# Trying to populate thread vector with a function - errors

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to populate a vector threads; with a function that iterates through a directory, but im running into problems

this is what I have:

```
//create vector of threads
vector<thread> threads;

for(unsigned i=0; i < threadNum; ++i)
{
    threads.push_back(thread(grep(arguments, r))); //best c++ 11
}
```

and this is the error that I am getting:

```
error c2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot conver from 'void' to std::thread
```

can anyone explain why and perhaps hint an answer? thank you

edit

grep is the function name

```
void grep(Arguments arguments, regex r){}
```

Comment: Is thread a function? because if it is then it could be returning void.

Comment: threads.push_back(thread(grep(arguments, r))); did you put "new" near the thread?

Comment: threads.push_back(new thread(grep(arguments, r)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you mean to say something like

```
threads.push_back(thread(grep, arguments, r));
```

or even better:

```
threads.emplace_back(grep, arguments, r);
```

Comment: will threads.push_back(thread(grep, arguments, r));
work if i need to pass grep 2 arguments?

Comment: i tried it and the errors have gone away, but how does this work? since i need to pass those two arguments(arguments,r) to grep? or does it work because its converting everything to a thread now?

Comment: @user1084319: That's how the `std::thread` class works... I don't think I can post a full tutorial in the comments :-S But let me know if you really really want me to explain this in greater detail.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I will take a look at the std::thread class

Comment: @user1084319 - here's a superficial, brief tutorial: the first argument to the thread constructor is the function to call; any additional arguments to the constructor are passed to that function when it is called in the new thread. So `thread(grep, arguments, r)` creates a new thread that runs the function `grep(arguments, r)`.

Comment: @user1084319: a `thread` object actually holds a *copy* of all your arguments, and when it's time to launch the thread (which happens automatically when you construct it the way you do), the function that you gave it is called with those copied arguments. So the way you construct a thread is by giving it a function and arguments. (Unlike what you tried, which is *evaluating* the function in the main thread.)